# Hibernate: Using part of composite FK in another entity PK

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

im relative new to Hibernate Mappings im trying to achieve this functionality between the class Post and Comentario without luck

[Relational model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRUvK.png)

```
@Embeddable
public class PostPK implements Serializable {

@Column(name="idPost")
private int postID;

@Column(name="idUsuario")
private int userIDFK;
-------------------------------
@Entity
@Table(name="Post")
public class Post {

@EmbeddedId
private PostPK id;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId(value="userIDFK")
@JoinColumn(name="idUsuario")
private Usuario usuario;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="post")
private List<Comentario> comentarios;

@Column(name="titulo")
private String titulo;

-----------------------------------
@Embeddable
public class ComentarioPK implements Serializable{

@Column(name="idComentario")
private int comentarioId;

@Column(name="idPost")
private int postIdFK;

---------------------------
@Entity
@Table(name="Comentario")
public class Comentario {

@EmbeddedId
private ComentarioPK id;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("postIdFK")
@JoinColumn(name="idPost",referencedColumnName="idPost")
private Post post;

@Column(name="texto")
private String texto;
```

without mapping comentario and its fields in Post its working fine but when i decide to map it i get this error 
**Unable to find column reference in the @MapsId mapping: idUsuario**

is it not finding the idUsuario column in Comentario table? i dont want to add it , i can achieve joins in mysql but i dont know how to do it in Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

`@MapsId` annotation is used to map the primary key fields of the parent entity with the child entity(with the same name). 
In your case your are having composite primary key in your parent entity but in child entity you want to refer only one field of it. 
`PostPK` has two fields : `idPost` and `idUsuario`. But in `Comentario` class when your are specifying ManyToOne relationship you are mentioning single column in `@JoinColumn`(which is idPost) and no field for `idUsuario` is available in your mapping. But as per the behavior of `@MapsId` annotation both the fields(`idPost` and `idUsuario`) are expected in  `Comentario` class.

Thus, in your case `@MapsId` annotation won't work

Comment: So i can't achieve what im looking (mapping one part of the key) at least in a direct way?

Comment: You can do it only by using @JoinColumn annotation. Within that use the attributes "name" and "refrencedColumn"

Comment: ok, if i remove the mapsId annotation and only use 

@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumns({    
 @JoinColumn(name="idPost",referencedColumnName="idPost"),
 @JoinColumn(name="idUsuario",referencedColumnName="idUsuario")
 })
 private Post post;

ERROR: Unknown column 'idUsuario' in 'field list'

and the SQL that hibernate is trying to perform is

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Comentario
        (idPost, userIDFK, texto, idComentario) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)

clearly not what i want

Comment: if instead try 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idPost",referencedColumnName="idPost")
private Post post;
, i get this error: 
referencedColumnNames(idPost) of Entidades.Comentario2.post referencing Entidades.Post not mapped to a single prope

Comment: It is because in ComentarioPK also you are mentioning the column idPost. You can add the attribute insertable=false,updatble=false while mentioning your joinColumn. In this way hibernate will understand that idPost will be inserted/updated via ComentarioPK only